# Z3 returns unknown

Tags: z3, smt

I have a simple set of constraints that Z3 is not able to cope with:

http://pastebin.com/3eaLQ9wx

Is there a way to tweak the constraints in order to get the result ? 
This is a simple example of a bigger set of constraints (thousands) but
I am somehow troubled that it doesn't work even on such simple example

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has non-linear constraints. While Z3 can deal with them in most cases, the mixing of `Int`s and `Real`'s seem to be putting it beyond its current capabilities. If you simply use `Real`s for your `s_0_1`, `s_0_2` etc. variables, I trust Z3 will be able to solve the problem. (You seem to have enough value constraints, so I trust there won't be a modeling issue.)

I think Leonardo expressed several times that the upcoming releases will have better support for combined theories in the presence of non-linear constraints.

Comment: Levent is correct, the problem is the use of mixed integer and real nonlinear arithmetic. I see two possible workarounds. We can replace all integer variables with real variables, this is ok, since the integer variables can only assume 0 or 1 values in your problem (here is this solution: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/ICFA). In this case the new nlsat solver in Z3 will be used. Another option is to replace the integer variables with Boolean ones, and linearize the problem using `If`s. Here is the link for this solution http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/egCe. The second solution should scale better.